Loading module from “.../_framework/dotnet.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)
My project runs fine on local host, but when I publish a Blazor WebAssembly app to Azure I get:
Loading module from “https://aistorybuilderstest.azurewebsites.net/_framework/dotnet.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).
aistorybuilderstest.azurewebsites.net
Loading failed for the module with source “https://aistorybuilderstest.azurewebsites.net/_framework/dotnet.js”. aistorybuilderstest.azurewebsites.net:73:52
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Failed to start platform. Reason: TypeError: error loading dynamically imported module: https://aistorybuilderstest.azurewebsites.net/_framework/dotnet.js
    mn https://aistorybuilderstest.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1

This project ran fine on Azure for months and I only made a small change to a .razor file. I had also upgraded the Nuget packages but I rolled back all those changes and it still wont work.
I created a new Blazor WebAssembly project and published to Azure and it also wont work.
It just shows:

I restored a back-up of a project that works and compared the files and I see that in the project that does not work the Dotnet.js files are missing.

Why are they missing? I have no idea :( I am running the latest Visual Studio Version 17.9.6
If I run the project locally the dotnet.js file is there and loads:


Right now, I published a new .NET 8 Blazor Standalone app (created from the "Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App" project template with Visual Studio 2022 Preview on Windows 11 Pro OS) to an Azure Web App instance using Visual Studio's "Publish" feature and it worked.
How did you publish your app? Did you use Visual Studio and its "Publish" GUI or dotnet CLI? CI/CD pipelines such as Azure DevOps, GitHub Actions, etc.?

I am not using Visual Studio Preview (can you see if it works for you if you use Visual Studio Version 17.9.6?). I am using the Visual Studio Publish wizard. I put a copy of the good and bad published versions here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n7i441e41jiun4m/GoodAndBadWebAssmbly.zip?dl=0

After investigating the files you provided me, I believe that the local publishing process (like "dotnet publish") is broken for some reason because the "blazor.boot.json" file in the "Bad" folder doesn't include the "dotnet.js" entry. It is really weird. Therefore, that must not be a problem around the Azure. However, I still have no idea why such a break happened. I'll retry it with my Visual Studio 17.9.6, but I think it won't matter. Why don't you try "dotnet publish" instead of using Visual Studio Publish Wizard and compare the published contents to the "Good" folder's contents?

I retried it with my Visual Studio 17.9.6, but unfortunately (?), it worked correctly. I could not reproduce your problem on my side. Can I access all of the site's source code? Can I try the publishing process on my side?

Thank you for looking at this. The source code for the project is here: https://github.com/AIStoryBuilders/AIStoryBuildersOnline

Thank you for providing the repository URL. Straight to the point, it worked correctly. My published site is here: https://demo-blazor-standalone-003.azurewebsites.net/
And I also noticed you resolved this problem in the next post by recreating a new Azure Web App instance. I have no idea why the difference in Azure Web App instances causes such a problem. But I'm happy to hear that the issue was resolved anyway.

I've pinpointed the issue to the Visual Studio publishing wizard failing to push all files, regardless of my efforts. Subsequently, I established a new Azure Web App under a fresh subscription, which resolved the issue. Thus, the publish destination seems to be the culprit, though the reason remains unclear. Nevertheless, I've devised a workaround by publishing to an alternative Azure WebApp.
** Update: The discrepancy between the sites where publishing is successful versus those where it isn't lies in the age of the Azure App Services; newer ones function correctly, while the older ones do not, despite previously operating without issue.

I don't know about your specific configuration nor how configuration works on azure. But I had a similar problem on my self-hosted server.
In my case it was because all requests are rewritten to index.html and that's why it has a mime type of text/html.

To solve this you could exclude the _framework folder (and some more probably, like _content) from the rewrite.

Nginx has an option to see if the file exists and only rewrite to index.html if it doesn't exist: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files



Thanks for responding. I updated my post to indicate that the required dotnet.js file is simply missing.
